# React Native - Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` from 'index.js'

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native, npm-start

As mentioned in [Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52486219/unable-to-resolve-module-babel-runtime-helpers-interoprequiredefault), I am experiencing the same error and the solution for that question doesn't solve the problem in my case.

Neither [React Native - Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56397626/react-native-unable-to-resolve-module-babel-runtime-helpers-interoprequirede) resolves my problem.

I am using

```
 OS: Windows 10 10.0.18362
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz
    Memory: 2.03 GB / 7.92 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.13.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.19.1 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
    npm: 6.12.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Version  3.5.0.0 AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
    react-native: 0.61.4 => 0.61.4
```

The error says:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` from `index.js`: @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\ReactProjects\testy\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:186:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\ReactProjects\testy\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\ReactProjects\testy\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:282:16)
    at Object.resolve (C:\ReactProjects\testy\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42)
    at C:\ReactProjects\testy\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:426:31
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\ReactProjects\testy\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:423:18)
    at C:\ReactProjects\testy\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\ReactProjects\testy\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1), failed.
```

The module exists and I have tried the mentioned steps but still it doesnt work.
The app actually builds successfully with message `Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.`
When the app runs the same error as above shows up.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue, without changing anything in the project. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @slhck It is kinda weird cause today it worked for me this way. I tried the whole setup again from the basics. I even uninstalled node and followed every step on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started . I don't think it made any difference but the only difference from last time was, I used Windows Terminal this time in place of cmd and Gradle 6.0-rc-1

Comment: and I didn't even need to do 'npx react-native start'. It worked fine on itself. Maybe it was a React issue after all.

Comment: I got it working by uninstalling `watchman`. See: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27712

Answer (score 4):

In [my case](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27712), the problem was not caused by RN, but by `watchman`.

There are two ways to solve this until a potential bug is fixed:

First would be to uninstall `watchman`.

Or manually edit the file `node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js` to change:

```
    const crawl =
      canUseWatchman && this._options.useWatchman
        ? _watchman.default
        : _node.default;
```

To:

```
    const crawl =
      canUseWatchman && this._options.useWatchman
        ? _node.default
        : _node.default;
```

The latter will of course not persist over package upgrades.